# Global windows hotkey to click web page in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

So i have some music webapp opened in chrome tab. Like pandora, mixcloud etc.. I want to have a keyboard shortcut that toggle play/pause button. Ideally without bringing the browser window active.

Comment: Operating System?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Some time ago I was pleasantly surprised to find that Google Music supports the OS-level media keys by default. Pretty nice. No idea how to get that to work with other media services though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you haven't stumbled up on [Streamkeys](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/streamkeys/ekpipjofdicppbepocohdlgenahaneen). Pandora and MixCloud are on the supported players [list](http://www.streamkeys.com/).

> Global hotkeys for online music players including support for media keys.

[image]

Comment: It works. Thank you! Chrome does not let me to use numpad keys as shortcut. But i think i can sort it out with Autohotkey or something. Otherwise - perfect. I guess this extension wasn't been around when a did a search couple years ago.